# Xamarin MasterPage set global PageStyle

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got this:

```
<MasterDetailPage
 [...]
 Style="{DynamicResource PageStyle}">
</MasterDetailPage>
```

PageStyle is defined in App.cs and sets the `BackgroundImage` property.

All other Pages should inherit the Background image, but they don´t.

Question is: Why? And how to fix?

Update:

**App.cs**

```
var GlobalStyle = new Style(typeof(MasterDetailPage))
      {
          Setters =
              new Setter {Property = Grid.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = "Black" },
              new Setter {Property = ListView.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = "Black" }
            }
      };
```

**MasterPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="MasterPage"
  Style="{StaticResource GlobalStyle}">
</MasterDetailPage>
```

It just plain ignores everything global

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better to use a global style?

Have a look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/#Using_Xaml_for_your_App).

Define styles in your app `ResourceDictionary` and you can also set to which type of page you want to apply it with the `TargetType` attribute.

So you'll get something like this

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="WorkingWithAppResources.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="backgroundImage" TargetType="MasterDetailPage">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundImage" Value="YourImage.png" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You should probably add an extra key for another type of page. But this way you don't have to include the `Style` attribute in every page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But how to accomplish this without XAML, just over the normal app.cs ?

Comment: Check this link for the same thing in code; https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/#Using_C_in_App.cs